# Highcharts color issue when using Boost module

Tags: highcharts

We are working with high volume of data but unfortunately for us Data grouping is not an option, but when using boost module, we have issue with colors kind of gray out.

You can see link to jsfiddle below, please comment boost script out to see the difference when not using Boost.

```
chart = Highcharts.stockChart('timeline_chart', {
            boost: {
                useGPUTranslations: true
            },
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x',
                animation: false,
                
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'center',
                backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderWidth: 2,
                shadow: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            navigator: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                align: 'center',
                text: '',
                
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
            },

            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                split: false,
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'white'],
                        [1, '#EEE']
                    ]
                },
                borderColor: 'gray',
                valueDecimals: 2,
            },
            yAxis: myYAxis,
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 2
                    },
                    animation: false,
                }
            },
            series: mySeries,
        });
    }
```

[Example in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yovanys7410/mnx7v8wr/18/)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

When you check the notes from the boost module you might see that the lines in area type series won't be drawn. That is why you might think that colours looks flatter.

```
 * Notes for boost mode
 * - Area lines are not drawn
 * - Lines are not drawn on scatter charts
 * - Zones and negativeColor don't work
 * - Dash styles are not rendered on lines.
 * - Columns are always one pixel wide. Don't set the threshold too low.
 * - Disable animations
 * - Marker shapes are not supported: markers will always be circles, except
 *   heatmap series, where markers are always rectangles.
```

Please compare these two charts:

1. Without the boost module and without the lines: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8u0so132/
2. With boost: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ugocansh/

They look very similar, I can even say that the one with boost looks sharper.

Comment: Thanks Karol, that answer my doubt!